# How to use each() to addClass for every matching row_id

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if it's possible to use each() to add a css class that would highlight each matching table row using JQuery. What I have is a PHP array of keys that I would like to match up to the corresponding table row ids. I'm still learning JQuery so I'm not that familiar with how this can be done.

Can someone either point me to a thread that shows this or maybe show me an example?

My table looks like this:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr id="row_23">
        <td>row 23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_24">
        <td>row 24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_25">
        <td>row 25</td>
    </tr>
</table>
...
```

EDIT:
PHP array:

```
array(
  [0]=>23
 ,[1]=>24
 ,[2]=>25
)
```

I want to match the value of the PHP array to the row id. For example: `<td>row 25</td>` should match PHP array key 2.

Comment: `$('tr').each(function(tr) { alert(tr.id === 'row_23' // or whatever); });` should work?

Comment: What do you mean by matching table row?

Comment: Thanks Bill. That looks like it would work but where do I put the incoming array values for each? I'm really new at this

Comment: @HanletEscaño. I've posted an edit for you

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean by match up. Does the table already exist? Do you create it with php? What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is in a `.php` file within a `<script>` section and your keys array is `$keys`

```
var idSelector = <?= json_encode($keys) ?>.map(function(k) {
    return '#row_' + k;
}).join(',');
$(idSelector).addClass('someClass');
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, Phil. Thank you for including the PHP json_encode() function. It's clear for me. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Wow, thank you, Phil! I'm going to pick up a book on JQuery. This is really cool! Thank you again!

Comment: @user1709311 I'd focus on JavaScript. The only jQuery is on the last line of my answer and it's arbitrarily simple

Comment: I think you're right. JavaScript looks more like a programming language and a lot of the constructs look familiar to me. JQuery just looks weird. It's not like anything I've seen before. If I can ask you a question about JQuery and its function construct.. What is this: `click(function(e)`. I know what the click function is but I see a function declaration with no function name. I'm used to seeing functions with names after them

Comment: That is what is called an anonymous function. It is handy when you do not need to call the function anywhere but in that spot. Anonymous functions are popular in javascript for defining event callback functions like in this case. If you wanted to could create a named function called `click_function` for example and called that from within the click handler, but in general it makes reading code simpler when using the anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

If you want highlight row_23, there are 3 ways:

```
var row_id = 'row_23';
var class_name = 'highlight';

$('#' + row_id).addClass(class_name);

// or
$('tr[id=' + row_id + ']').addClass(class_name);

// or
$('tr').each(function(
    if (this.id == row_id) {
        $(this).addClass(class_name);
    }
))
```

if you want highlight the 2nd tr, try this:

```
$('tr').eq(1).addClass(class_name);
```

Comment: Wow, you mean that in your first two examples, I wouldn't need to iterate over the results?

Comment: Sure, that's the most efficient way.